# How to create a Realistic Moon

Tags: dynamic-topology

So I recently saw a video of a highly realistic lunar surface made just using micropoligon displacement. Now I was curious if we could create such realistic landscapes without a height map? 
Also, how can I recreate this exact same texture/material that they used in this video?

The link to the video is this: https://youtu.be/Z9bGr3HWqLg

Answer (score 4):

The best way to map the moon is to use an actual height map.  You can find a free usable map here: https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub

Nothing beats the real thing.  If you want to add more detail, use a noise displacement on top of it.